# Mouse cursor is invisible in latest ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse, 22.04, cursor

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for my work. After sometime the cursor becomes invisible. I can still use the mouse to open folders but without the cursor its very hard. So I googled and did everything in other posts but nothing worked( ex installing gdm , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> trick, reinstalling lightdm ) then I tried a different Linux distro such xubuntu,kubuntu ,linux mint , manjaro xfce , manjaro kde but have the same problem in all of them. I have three mouse and none of theme required any drivers. What should I do I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu and this error is making it even worse.

Edit(list of things I did):

1. `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false` tried this command and restart the system.
2. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then run the updates and restart.
3. `sudo service lightdm restart`.
4. `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse`.
5. Tried to install gdm but got some kind of error I dont remember the error.
6. I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> .
7. Tried different distros: manjaro (xfce,kde,mate), xubuntu, linux mint, Endevaour OS(KDE) and some other OS.

I am not using any themes/or any installed programms other than chrome and vscode . Is this because I am using wireless mouse? I have three mouses, all of them are wireless.

Any advice will be helpful. thank you.

Comment: Please  list what you have done from other posts. Otherwise you may just get answers telling you to do what you have already done.

Comment: Hey @David, thanks for info I edited the question with what I tried .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04. I saw the hover effects, but not mouse pointer.

I changed to Xorg in the login screen and it works fine.

[image: in the login screen change to Xorg]